# Creating Chart In Pure PHP Example

Tags: php

I have really been struggling with how to approach this problem, so I thought it would warrant it to open a new question to get some help from someone more experienced.

I am working on the following example to create a very simple chart in pure PHP http://code.web-max.ca/image_graph.php

**Problem**

I am adding my code, **I have commented the problems I am having in the code**  **mostly in capitals.**

The problem occurs below when the `$maxv` variable is set to `0` which leads to an error division by zero...however when I copy and paste only the example to my editor and run it, it is working so there must be a logical problem in my code somewhere, I am attaching a screenshot aswell as my code.....any help much appreciated

**IMG OF My Output**
[image]

```
    //create array retrieved from DB in code ABOVE and add "" and , to each value
        foreach($t1Picks as $key => $nr){
            $values[] = '"'.$nr.'"'.','; 

        }

         echo '$values are fine'. implode($values);
        echo '<br />';
    //values are fine.....go ahead

    // Get the total number of columns we are going to plot
        $columns  = count($values);
         echo 'COLUMN COUNT IS FINE'.$columns;
        echo '<br />';
    //columns count is fine continue
    // Get the height and width of the final image

        $width = 300;
        $height = 200;

    // Set the amount of space between each column

        $padding = 5;

    // Get the width of 1 column

       $column_width = $width / $columns;
       $column_width = round($column_width, 0);

       echo 'COLUMN WIDTH IS FINE'.$column_width;
       echo '<br />';
        // Generate the image variables

        $im        = imagecreate($width,$height);
        $gray      = imagecolorallocate ($im,0xcc,0xcc,0xcc);
        $gray_lite = imagecolorallocate ($im,0xee,0xee,0xee);
        $gray_dark = imagecolorallocate ($im,0x7f,0x7f,0x7f);
        $white     = imagecolorallocate ($im,0xff,0xff,0xff);

        // Fill in the background of the image

         imagefilledrectangle($im,0,0,$width,$height,$white);

       $maxv = 0; //I DONT UNDERSTAND THIS 
       //WHY MAX VAL 0? 

    // Calculate the maximum value we are going to plot

        for($i=0;$i<$columns;$i++)$maxv = max($values[$i],$maxv); //WHY NO BRACE { ON FOR 
        echo 'MAXV TEST IS'.$maxv; //THE FIRST LOOP IS 9 AND THEN ZEROS
        echo'<br />';
  // Now plot each column
```

Thank you very much for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things I've noticed. It looks like you're adding a comma to each element in your `$values` array.

```
$values[] = '"'.$nr.'"'.',';
```

I would change that to this instead.

```
$values[] = $nr;
```

Then change your implode line to this...

```
echo '$values are fine'. implode(", ", $values);
```

Next, I don't see anyplace in your example code that you're doing division except here...

```
$column_width = $width / $columns;
```

So the only time you should get a division by zero error would be if you had no values in your `$values` array.

Comment: thank you very much, let me check, then I will get back to you shortly

Comment: p.s I only added part of the example since I am debugging section for section hence no division, have a look at example link if you don't mind

Comment: UPDATE: since changing the foreach loop and implode as recomended the first `$maxv` value echo'ed is now 15 and NOT 9 which is a step in the right direction....however after that still all zeros

Comment: Seems to me the comma should have been your issue. If you look here... http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php it explains that `max(0, 'hello');` will result in 0. So, you were accidentally creating strings for your values that you were then supplying to the max function. It was then returning your zeros. Did you remove the quotes as I suggested in my answer as well?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee what do you mean, "after that still all zeros"?  Where are you seeing the zeros?

Comment: I mean I get the error divison by zero.....we are very close to solving it the only problem is your implode suggestion only glues `,` between the numbers and no `""` as in the example. Here is an echo'ed example of the implode you suggested `15, 9, 6, 11, 4, 6, 8, 1, 9, 6, 4, 11, 7, 8, 5, 10, 6, 9 ` Which is good I just need to find a way to add the `""` between the numbers as in the example. EXAMPLE: it should read `"15","9","6"` etc

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Why do you need the quotes around the numbers? Aren't you really trying to work with integers in your chart, not strings? You're doing math with those values, which says to me that you would want them as I have explained and not with the quotes around them. Just my opinion.

Comment: I KNOW AND I FULLY AGREE BUT LOOK AT EXAMPLE LINK

Comment: anyway I found a way of glueing the values together like `"15","9","6"` so lets see what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106847/discussion-between-throwbackdewd-and-timothy-coetzee).